# User.IsInRole() not working in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, isinrole

I know this question is asked many times. I tried all solutions but not getting it worked. I a using MVC4 and using forms authentication. I am not using membership but want to store roles in Forms Authentication. I am using below code to achieve my goal.

```
 FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(result.ID.ToString(), false);
                GenericPrincipal gp = new GenericPrincipal(HttpContext.User.Identity, new string[] { "admin" });
                HttpContext.User = gp;
```

I am getting username and IsAuthenticated successfully using `User.Identity.Name` and `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` but when I am trying to check role using code `var role = User.IsInRole("admin");` it is returning false.

Please help.

Comment: Where are you storing the roles?

Comment: @DavidTansey I don't know much about roles. I checked on google about how to use role without using membership and got above code. Everything is working fine except role. If you will see, I have mentioned admin role in GenericPrinciple.